# How to workaround Gmail CSS image display bug?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, mailchimp

When viewing an email with images off in Gmail, embedded styles will initially load correctly. However, if you click the “Display images below” link to turn images on, that causes Gmail to re-render the email markup with a different prefix for the class names and IDs.

The problem is, the email is still being styled with the previous version of the stylesheet, without updating the prefixes to match the current markup.

This means any CSS rule that depends on class name or ID selectors will stop working the moment images are turned on, leaving only element name or wildcard selectors.

I am currently using mailchimp to pass in an image, but I don't have access to that image element in the code (just the merge tag |IMAGE|) When this issue arises in Gmail, I can't access that image element. Any idea how to accomplish this?

```
<style>
.share-img img{
max-width: 60%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.share-img img{
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
}   
</style>
<div class="share-img" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">*|IMAGE|*</div>
```

edit:

Here's an example of how gmail prepends classes/ID's with unique strings. The stylesheet 'share-img' class and the actually 'share-img' class have 2 different strings before them thus it is not resizing the image properly.

[gmail inspect element image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Luba.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Any chance we can see the code the image before and after being sent? If its merge tag is it going thru your list or is it conditional statement or something else?

Comment: so that is the code being sent before it is being sent. it is going through my list, so it populates the image tag with the correct image in the database. I'll edit my answer to include what gmail does to it.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the space before `480px` in your media query. Gmail is very annoying with CSS support. I have a feeling that's breaking it. Use the below code and see if it works now.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
.share-img img{
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
}
```

Cheers